# How to export MATLAB code for a Linux System that don't have MATLAB installed?

Tags: python, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I have MATLAB installed on my Windows PC. What I want is to export some MATLAB code to a Linux server that don't have MATLAB installed. I would like to call that MATLAB code from my Python code. I can install MATLAB runtime on Linux system if that don't require a License. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab has to be purchased.  There is an open-source package called Octave that is a very close to Matlab, at https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/index.

However, the Python `numpy` and `scipy` modules essentially implement everything that's in Matlab, often with the same spellings.  If your Matlab code is not thousands of lines long, you might be better served by recoding it as Python code using `numpy` and `scipy`.

Comment: Thanks Tim! but I have to use gtcc features extraction function in Matlab. https://www.mathworks.com/help/audio/ref/gtcc.html  Otherwise, I'm a big fan of Python and very comfortable with Python. but Python don't have an implementation for gtcc.

Comment: What you "have to" use doesn't change MATLAB's licensing model, you will likely have to buy a license to the MATLAB runtime and any toolboxes you're using. Or you could buy a license to the MATLAB compiler and compile your code, but it is also not free.